# Modifying styles of a compiled html element in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

**UPDATE**

I think I found the issue, the template variable is lossing it's value, I don't get why yet, I've changed the code a bit:

```
      var template;

      $templateRequest("ng-templates/app/cart-counter.html").then(function(html){
        template = angular.element(html);
        element.append(template);
        $compile(template)(scope);
        console.log("template: " + template); // This returns the template object
      });

      var unbindWatcher = scope.$watch(
        "clickCounter",
        function(newClickCounter){
          console.log("template: " + template); // This returns undefined
          if (newClickCounter >= 5) {
            var cartButton = this.template.children('.btn');

            cartButton.toggleClass('btn-success'); // this throws undefined error

            unbindWatcher();
          }
        }
      );
```

My question now would be why is the template variable undefined when it had a value earlier and what should I do to fix it?

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I am playing around with Angular, trying to change some elements classes by compiling an html adding it to the DOM and when an event happens, I am trying to use angularElement to access the childs of the html I compiled and toggling some classes.

This is not giving me an error, but the changes in the classes are not happening and I can't find what Im doing wrong, please help.

This is the code for the directive:

```
store.directive("appCartCounter", ['$templateRequest', '$compile', function($templateRequest, $compile){
    var link = function(scope, element){
      this.messages = [
        "Sorry, the shopping cart is not implemented",
        "Hey, I told you, it's not ready",
        "Stop that! It's anoying",
        "I'm getting really really angry",
        "YEarghhh!!!!"
      ];

      scope.messages = this.messsages;
      scope.clickCounter = 0;
      scope.incrementCount = function(){
        scope.clickCounter++;
      };

      $templateRequest("ng-templates/app/cart-counter.html").then(function(html){
        this.template = angular.element(html);
        element.append(template);
        $compile(template)(scope);
      });

      var unbindWatcher = scope.$watch(
        "clickCounter",
        function(newClickCounter){
          console.log("I've been watching you... alalalong");
          if (newClickCounter >= 5) {                
            var cartButton = this.template.children('.btn');
            var messageElement = this.template.children('.text-info');
            cartButton.toggleClass('btn-success');
            cartButton.toggleClass('btn-danger');
            cartButton.toggleClass('btn-lg');

            messageElement.toggleClass('text-info');
            messageElement.toggleClass('text-danger');
            messageElement.toggleClass('text-capitalize');
            messageElement.toggleClass('lead');

            unbindWatcher();
            console.log("I'm blind!!");
          }
        }
      );

    };

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        'addedProducts' : '='
      },
      replace: 'true',
      link: link
    };
  }]);
```

cart-counter.html:

```
<button
  class="btn btn-success"
  data-ng-show="addedProducts.length"
  data-ng-click="incrementCount()"
  data-ng-cloak>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i> {{addedProducts.length}}
</button>
<p data-ng-show="clickCounter" class="text-info">
  {{messages[clickCounter]}}
</p>
```

html using the directive:

```
<app-cart-counter data-added-products="storeCtrl.addedProducts"></app-cart-counter>
```

I'll try to get a simpler example in a plunker.

Thanks!!

Comment: I am curious if there was a reason you used $compile vs. returning templateUrl: 'ng-templates/app/cart-counter.html' in your directive? You would have to set a watch for changes, and then remove/re-add the template if you are doing it this way.

Comment: besides the reason of trying to understand angular better (it was using templateUrl first), following some tutorials, I understood that having the html as a variable was an easier and cleaner way of accesing the elements.
This is the tutorial I was following:
https://thinkster.io/egghead/angular-element
The difference is that I needed to compile the element because of the bindings.
Also, I don't understand why would I need to remove and re-add the template, I'm not doing that

Comment: One update, from what I'm seeing, it seems that the value of this.template that is inside $templateRequest is different from the one in the function(newClickCounter).
This is also strange because the reason I moved it from var template to this.template was because trying to access the template on the function was throwing me an undefined error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to "fix" the problem by saving the template to the scope, altough I still don't understand why the variable or the saving it to "this." didn't worked.

As a sidenote, selecting the children via tagname didn't worked, I also tried with the children number and classname (even though I have jquery imported in the solution). To solve that, I had to access the elements via the template object's array, and wrap that in an angular.element(), eg:

```
var cartButton = angular.element(scope.template[0]);
var messageElement = angular.element(scope.template[2]);
```

PS: scope.template[1] returned me a text node because of the linebreak, I hadn't expected that.